# How to exclude a specific directory from directory check in .htacess file

Tags: .htaccess

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Currently all directory present are not allowed to reach the index.php  file according to this conditions.

How can I disable the directory condition check for a specific directory. Basically I want specifically `/mydirectory` to pass through this and eventually call the index.php .

Comment: What URL do you want to use in browser for this request?

Comment: _“eventually call the index.php”_ - you mean you want the index document _from_ that directory to be served? (So basically what the default behavior would be, if no rewriting at all happened in the first place.) Just add a 3rd RewriteCond then, that makes sure the `REQUEST_URI` was not `/mydirectory`?

Comment: Just the directory itself or that directory + all _files_ inside that directory?

Comment: @misorude Adding a third condition for /mydirectory check? It would fail on the second condition and break right?  And then the directory would be served. I don't want directory to be served. I want the request to be passed to index.php even if there is directory named /mydirectory

Comment: @MrWhite Not only the directory but everything inside it. `/mydirectory/*` I want everything to be skipped from this condition and then pass on to index.php

Comment: _“It would fail on the second condition and break right?”_ - multiple RewriteCond are joined with an implicit AND.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to rewrite the directory and all files in that directory, it's not just the *directory* check you need to exclude, but also the *file* check.

You could just add another rule for this directory. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Force all requests to /mydirectory/<anything> to go to index.php
# Regardless of whether it exists or not
RewriteRule ^(mydirectory/.*) index.php/$1 [L]

# Rewrite everything to index.php, providing it doesn't exist as a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

All requests to `/mydirectory/<anything>` are also routed to `index.php`.

Comment: How is it "not working" exactly? Do you get an error, incorrect rewrite, nothing? What URL are you requesting? Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file? Any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: I was getting 500 server error and other routes also are not working and getting same error.

Comment: Check your server's error log for the details of this error. "Other routes" should not be affected by this, unless you are referencing resources in the generated pages that are also in the URL-path `/mydirectory/<something>`?